# Use $scope data in <script> in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have data which is stored in $scope.cars in my main.js. Now I understand how to get this data in HTML using {{cars}}. However, this does not work in "script" tags. In the following code you can see my code which is located in main.js.

```
$http( {
method: "GET",
url : $scope.myUrl,
headers : {'Accept':'application/sparql-results+json', 'Content-Type':'application/sparql-results+json'}
} )
.success(function(data, status ) {
    $scope.cars1 = [];
    $scope.result = data;
    angular.forEach(data.results.bindings, function(val) { 
        $scope.newObject = {};
        $scope.newObject.Brand = val.brand.value;
        $scope.newObject.Fuel = val.fuel.value;
        $scope.newObject.Gearbox = val.gearbox.value;
        $scope.newObject.Price = val.price.value;
        $scope.newObject.Horsepower = val.hp.value;
        $scope.newObject.Mileage = val.mileage.value;
        $scope.newObject.Info = val.info.value;
        $scope.newObject.Year = val.year.value;
        $scope.newObject.Longitude = val.long.value;
        $scope.newObject.Latitude = val.lat.value;
        $scope.cars1.push($scope.newObject);
    });
    $scope.cars = GeoJSON.parse($scope.cars1, {Point: ['Latitude', 'Longitude']});
})

.error(function(error ){
    console.log('Error '+error);
});
```

Is there any way to convert the data in the $scope.cars to a variable (var cars) or use the $scope.cars inside the script?

I want to use the data in the following function inside my script which is located in index.html.

```
  // This adds the data to the map
  map.on('load', function (e) {
      // This is where your '.addLayer()' used to be, instead add only the 
      //source without styling a layer
      map.addSource("places", {
      "type": "geojson",
      "data": cars
   });
   // Initialize the list
   buildLocationList(cars);
});
```

Comment: Just move the map init code inside your angular app.

Comment: @ChrisG I appreciate your answer, however when I try copying the whole script to my main.js. Everything seems to stop working. For example I have a {{cars}} in my HTML to show the data that's in $scope.cars, but that only shows {{cars}} now instead of the data inside of it.

Comment: I don't think copying the whole script is the answer here; maybe this will help: https://github.com/Naimikan/angular-mapboxgl-directive